# Parsing C code to generate a flattened equivalent

Tags: c, parsing, gcc, clang

I need to parse C code to generate a "flattened" Prolog readable form for static analysis purposes.
e.g.

```
int map (int den, int a) {
  den = den*(a+a);
  if (den == 90) return -1/(den-90);
  else return -2;
}
```

becomes something like:

```
function_definition(map,[declaration(int,[Den]),
                         declaration(int,[A])],
[assignment(Den,multiply(Den,(A+A))),
 if_statement(8,expression(Den==90),[return(-1/(Den-90))],[return(-2)])
],int).
```

The only semantics information required is the cross-referencing of identifiers so they can be matched to unique identifiers in Prolog.

In the past I have used Lex/Yacc to build parsers to do this job. But this is cumbersome (many official C versions, many proprietary variants, hard to debug, still relying on external pre-processors (e.g. GCC's) to deal with macros and locating files).

What is the alternative?
Using GCC or CLang Abstract Syntax Tree? But the learning curve for these appear huge (at least for CLang, several months at least, if not open-ended for anything but toy code).

Using a more modern non LALR(1) parser generator? I did try ANTLR without benefits.

Parsing efficiency is not a primary concern, but the ability to handle large scale industrial C code is, and so is maintainability.

Comment: Use `LLVM` and process the `AST` (abstract syntax tree)? It has [used to, at least] have a utility that can dump it to a [parsible] text form.

Comment: "Flattened" seems a pretty ironic description of the result you're looking for.

Comment: I can see that "macro mayhem" will make your analysis difficult.  Both preprocessed and unpreprocessed source will present problems.  If you've not had to work with systems using macros like `#define ONCE while (0)` — for use with `do { …loop… } ONCE;` — or `#define FOREVER while (1)` — for use with either `FOREVER { …loop… }` or `do { …loop… } FOREVER;` — then you're lucky so far.  And they're not the worst macros that can be devised to disguise the language.